# Stuck on Vector Projection

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, projection-matrices

[Visualization of this projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkU7u.png)

I'm currently learning about projecting a vector onto a subspace, and the first step in doing so is recognizing that b = z + w (see picture). Can someone familiar with linear algebra shed light on why this is the case and explain because my intuition says Pythagorean theorem but...

Comment: You are adding the vectors, not their lengths.

Comment: Ah ok, lol my bad thank you.

Comment: Please do not link to outside sources. All relevant info should be in the problem. Also, it isn't a big deal here, but for the future, LaTeX markup is highly encouraged.